# c3p0 throws com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException when using ComboPooledDataSource with Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, c3p0

I'm trying to set up a c3p0 connection pool for a spring/hibernate application using a Postgres DB and i'm unable to connect to server.

If i use "org.postgresql.jdbc2.optional.PoolingDataSource" the application can connect to DB but if i use "com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" it hangs for a while and then throws:
"com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source."

Here is the class for the datasource

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    public class JpaConfigurator {

        @Bean
        public DataSource getDataSource() throws PropertyVetoException {

    //      PoolingDataSource  dataSource =  new PoolingDataSource();
    //      dataSource.setServerName("localhost");
    //      dataSource.setPortNumber(5432);
    //      dataSource.setDatabaseName("projeto_jpa");
    //      dataSource.setUser("postgres");
    //      dataSource.setPassword("pass");
    //      dataSource.setInitialConnections(2);
    //      dataSource.setMaxConnections(5);
    //
            ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClass("org.postgresql.Driver");
            dataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/projeto_jpa");
            dataSource.setUser("postgres");
            dataSource.setPassword("pass");
            dataSource.setMinPoolSize(5);
            dataSource.setNumHelperThreads(5);

            return dataSource;
        }

        @Bean
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

            entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("br.com.caelum");
            entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);

            entityManagerFactory
                    .setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());

            Properties props = new Properties();

            props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect");
            props.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
            props.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");

            entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(props);
            return entityManagerFactory;
        }

        @Bean
        public JpaTransactionManager getTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
            JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
            transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

            return transactionManager;
        }

    }
```

And the following is the main class for test

```
    public class TestPool {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws PropertyVetoException, SQLException, InterruptedException{


    //      PoolingDataSource datasource = (PoolingDataSource) new JpaConfigurator().getDataSource();

            ComboPooledDataSource datasource = (ComboPooledDataSource) new JpaConfigurator().getDataSource();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                datasource.getConnection();
                System.out.println("Got connection " + i);

            }

        }

    }
```

It seems to be some kind of configuration problem while using c3p0. Any ideas to what could it be?

Full Exception stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:529)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
    at br.com.caelum.TestPool.main(TestPool.java:18)
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1319)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue with c3p0 while I was upgrading to PostgreSQL 10. It was not able to acquire connections from database. While researching on the issue, I came over this blog [Connection Pool Analysis](https://beansroasted.wordpress.com/2017/07/29/connection-pool-analysis/) and switched over HikariCP. Its better than C3p0 in terms of performance as well as if you want to upgrade your database then HikariCP has better support.